# Google BigQuery System Status Page?

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a page that allows me to see the system status of Google BigQuery?  I'm seeing very long request times to just the Google BigQuery API today (via web browser).  Some calls are returning a 503 -

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "backendError",
    "message": "Backend Error"
   }
  ],
  "code": 503,
  "message": "Backend Error"
 }
}
```

EDIT: Delays and 503s disappeared as of 4:05 MDT today.

Comment: API calls to BigQuery often fail with a 503 response. Just try them again after a short period of time and then they will succeed.

Comment: @Mark Thanks for the suggestion, but that didn't work in my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only page that I know of right now is the [bigquery-downtime-notify page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bigquery-downtime-notify).

Other than that, I watch on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-bigquery) if others have a similar problem. 
I also watch the [BigQuery issues page](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list) where users can report bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can now check this new page: https://status.cloud.google.com/

You can get info about most of the Google Cloud Platform products (App Engine, Google Cloud Platform, BigQuery, etc).

Comment: The status for BigQuery there does not appear to have been updated since 2014.